# Deserializing a JSON in Java which contains __type instead of @class

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I am working on a JSON, which looks like this:

```
 "locale": {
    "__type": "com.package1.package2.className",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
                    }
```

Earlier, I used to get the following JSON:

```
 "locale": {
    "@class": "com.package1.package2#<className>",
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
                    }
```

Now, before the changes happened in a downstream service I was able to de-serialize the json and map these values to class, but now since @class has been replaced with __type, the deserializer is not working.

How do I convert __type to @class.

I don't want to use replace functionality, since the JSON is a lot more complex then shown above, also since its very hacky. Is there a library which can do this on its own? I have no control over the JSON which I receive.

I don't want to write my own POJO for this, since the same is already available in a different package but has className as its parameter instead of __type.

Comment: Not an answer, but just to check. You have a white list of classes you're prepared to deserialise right? Not just any arbitrary class this JSON you have no control over asks for?

Comment: Is __type just containg the simple class name; e.g. Date? (rather than for example java.util.Date). If so the whole thing is impossible as there may be many classes on your classpath that have the same simple name

Comment: @RichardTingle Yes, I have the <className> which I want deserialise.

Comment: @RichardTingle __type contains the whole class path. Have updated the question to reflect the same.

Comment: Could you please share your POJO here

Comment: Solution might depend on the way you deserialize. The desearializer is not working so why not to show the code for it?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your deserializer, I cannot figure out why it was not working. But if you can create your own POJOs for this, it will be much easier by using `@JsonAlias` (in Jackson).

**POJOs**

```
class MyPojo {
    private Locale locale;

    //general getters and setters
}

class Locale {
    @JsonAlias({"__type", "@class"})
    private String typeOrClass;

    private String key1;
    private String key2;
    private String key3;

    //general getters and setters
}
```

**Code snippet**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyPojo myPojo = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, MyPojo.class);
```